# What is this microwave component?

Tags: identification, components, microwave

I am at-home electronics hobbyist and tend to salvage majority of the components I use from old/broken items. Recently I took apart a microwave and desoldered most of the the components from it. I have never seen one of these (picture) before. What is this and what does it do?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per multiple requests an official answer:

> What is this

It is a Piezo buzzer.

> and what does it do?

It beeps.

Comment: It isn't really a buzzer, since it can't beep without additional circuitry.  Isn't it really a piezo transducer or speaker?